# Calling an overloaded method

Tags: java, overloading

how is it to make an overloaded method do the same plus their new functionality?
Without copying the same code again.

Something like this:

```
void method(){

//code 1
}

void method(String s){

//code 1
//code 2
}
```

Comment: Refactor the common code into a private method?

Comment: `I cannot find any example of this for this specific case.` This is the **whole point** of overloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to refactor the common code into a private method:

```
void method(){

  common();
}

void method(String s){

  common();
//code 2
}

private void common() {
   // code 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main class:

```
public void foo() {
    System.out.println("main method");
}
```

In the extending class:

```
public void foo(String s) {
    foo();
    System.out.println(s + "from overloading method");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void method(){

//code 1
}

void method(String s){

method();
//code 2
}
```

Comment: Please expand your answer with description / explanation. Code-only answers are highly discouraged and not very helpful.